# Unity Non player objects movements are not syncronized on server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, unityscript, multiplayer

Hi everyone I'am struggling with this problem from a very long time.

I have a scene object (a cube) that can be moved by the client. The problem is that its movements are not seen on server.

The cube has a network identity and network transform component. To sync its movements i'am using `[Command]` (based on the example I found here http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.CommandAttribute.html).

I've found out that the problem is that, the statement:

```
if (NetworkServer.active)
```

is never true.

Could anyone help me please? Thank you so much

Comment: Are you joining the server? According to unity documentation "This will be true after NetworkServer.Listen() has been called.". Are you calling that?

Comment: Yes I think I am joining the server because I can see other players in the scene..